# How to make sessions work in IIS with ASP . NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, session, iis, cookies

I have been trying to determine what is causing Session values to be null in my ASP .NET Core application, reading a lot of documentation in this site and in Microsoft Docs and I think I either have not grasped the general idea behind Sessions in .NET Core or simply am missing something.
The webpage is .NET Core 3.1 and everything works wonderfully when running in IIS Express and even deployed on my local IIS, however, Session values don't seem to work when deployed to remote server.

(EDIT: To be precise, Sessions values in the remote server behave erratically, sometimes they work for less than one minute, and sometimes they don't work at all)

From what I have read, I think Sessions won't work unless I have some kind of implementation of IDistributedCache, but I haven't given myself the time to fully implement this, although I thought of SqlServerCache. So I'm using the default implementation of Microsoft, which is not recommended for production, but anyway. The relevant part of the `Startup.cs` file is:

```
services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);//You can set Time   
        });
```

And the full `Startup.cs` is here:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Index";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnValidatePrincipal = async contexto =>
                {
                    var accessToken = contexto.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Type == "AccessToken");
                    if (accessToken == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contexto.Principal.Identity.Name) || !contexto.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    var userService = contexto.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                    var userName = contexto.Principal.Identity.Name;

                    var usuario = await userService.ValidateUser(userName, String.Format("{0}{1}", Configuration.GetSection("ApiPath").Value, "TecaltUser/GetUsers"), (accessToken != null ? accessToken.Value : String.Empty));
                    if (usuario.Item1)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    contexto.RejectPrincipal();
                    await contexto.HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
                }
            }; // AGREGAR LA COOKIE AL SERVICIO DE AUTENTICACIÓN
        });
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);//You can set Time   
        });
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, DALUser>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

So I think it seems like I have explored most of the options, like setting the `ExpireTimeSpan` of the cookie, setting the `CheckConsentNeeded` option to false, because I didn't know it was true by default and in that case the user must explicitly would have to consent the cookies, isn't it?
So my question is, is it really hard to set the Session in ASP .NET Core? I sincerely can't tell if there is something in my code that fails to make it work (by the way, the cookie is set after getting a JWT from a separate web api, also in .NET Core).

Regards to everyone and if someone can help with a reasonable or even obvious thing I'm not considering I would be very thankful

I have kept on adding options but still nothing seems to work, I added these lines after calling `DistributedMemoryCache`:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);//You can set Time   
        });
```

And even changed from EndPointRouting to Mvc (I thought incorrectly it seems that it might have something related):

```
services.AddMvc(options=>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });
```

Then finally I invoke them:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

But still no results whenever I deploy to remote server. Seriously, is it that hard to work with Sessions?

Comment: I also forgot to add that I can see the Session Cookies in the browser with their default names "AspNetCore.Session" and "AspNetCore.Cookies" but like I said apparently their value is null

Comment: Could you please tell me how you host your application? Do you enable  the loadbalance in your server?

Comment: @BrandoZhang I host in a windows server with IIS as proxy and InProcess mode. I don't think it's load balanced since it's a single site, not a web farm

Comment: Although there are two more sites on the same folder root, one is for the API, but I don't think they are related

Comment: It's IIS 10 by the way

Comment: I contacted the staff in the hosting account and they suggested that I added the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session so I thought that must be it because AspNet Core is modular so the server doesn't have installed the full NET Core. But I was wrong, and the effort was useless. By the way I mention that although I added the package, no dll for that package is present in the deployed folder. Sigh...

Comment: Yes, this issue is so strange. Normally, if we use AddDistributedMemoryCache that means we will use inprocess memory by default.  I suggest you could also check if your browser has disabled the cookie or not

Answer (score 0):

The issue remains strange indeed as [Brando Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7609093/brando-zhang) pointed. I wasn't able to use sessions on that server with ASP .NET Core 3.1. However, we ended up using only the authentication cookie and it's working well that way, so it only required minor changes like the following where we were using sessions:

```
public JsonResult AddToCart(int ProductId, int Quantity = 1)
    {
        // GFB CORRECCIÓN SESIÓN NO SE OBTIENE
        //DTOUser User = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<DTOTecalt.Users.DTOUser>("LoadedUser");
        //if (User != null)
        //{
            CartModel Cart = new CartModel();//GetCart();
            List<DTOCart> Lines = new List<DTOCart>();
            
            //DTOUser User = HttpContext.Session.GetJson<DTOTecalt.Users.DTOUser>("LoadedUser");
            int IdUser = 0;
            if(HttpContext.User.Identities.SelectMany(a => a.Claims).FirstOrDefault(r => r.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) != null)
            int.TryParse(HttpContext.User.Identities.SelectMany(a => a.Claims).FirstOrDefault(r => r.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value, out IdUser);
            if (IdUser != 0)
            {
                
                Tuple<string, List<DTOCart>, DTOSummaryCart> _result = new Tuple<string, List<DTOCart>, DTOSummaryCart>(ConstantesWeb.ERROR_PREDET, Lines, new DTOSummaryCart());
                using (DALCart Accion = new DALCart())
                {
                    _result = Accion.GetTotalsCart(IdUser);
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_result.Item1))
                {
                    return Json(new { ErrorInterno = ConstantesWeb.ERROR_PREDET });
                }
                Lines = _result.Item2;
            }
            else
            {
            return Json(new { Unauthorized = true });
            }

        Cart.AddItem(new DTOCart { ProductItem = new Products.DTOProduct { IdProduct = ProductId } }, Quantity, new DTOUser { IdUser = IdUser });
            List<DTOCart> _resultCart = new List<DTOCart>();
            Tuple<bool, string> AddCart = new Tuple<bool, string>(false, ConstantesWeb.ERROR_PREDET);
            using (DALCart Accion = new DALCart())
            {
                List<DTOCart> Products = Cart.Lines.ToList();
                AddCart = Accion.UpdateCart(Products);
                
            }
            if(!AddCart.Item1)
            {
                return Json(new { ErrorInterno = ConstantesWeb.ERROR_CARRITO_ADD });
            }
            SaveCart(Cart);
            //HttpContext.Session.SetJson("Cart", Cart);
            return Json(new { Exito = true });
        //}
    }
```

I wanted to post the actual solution we took for reference, you can see I commented out references to HttpContext.Session